# What is most optimal way to truncate a string to limit its length?

Tags: java, string

I am writing a function to limit the length of a sentence. Say limit is 15, and the sentence is "SO is great website". I don't want to truncate it exactly at the 15th position, otherwise the truncated sentence would become "SO is great web". But, what I want to do is to truncate from the first space before the limit. It would give me "SO is great".

One way of doing it is

> int firstIndexOfSpaceBeforeGIvenIndex= str.lastIndexOf(" ", 15);
>
> str = StringUtils.truncate(str, 0, firstIndexOfSpaceBeforeGIvenIndex);

The string could be very long and I have to perform this operation on thousands of strings. So performance is my concern. What is the most optimal way to achieve this task?

Comment: I'm not familiar with StringUtils.truncate, but in principle, what you're doing looks fine to me.  Don't forget to deal with the cases where (1) the original String is shorter than 15 characters, and (2) the first 15 characters are all non-space.

Comment: I could be missing something, but I see no point in using a third party library for this when we have `str.substring(0, firstIndexOfSpaceBeforeGIvenIndex)`. Or maybe your `StringUtils` take some of the conditions mentioned by @DavidWallace into account??

Comment: Performance is your concern but did make experiment? Are you sure that is not good for thousands? Is it thousands or millions? billions? I doubt any more effort will be necessary for thousands of strings. Never make premature optimization.

Comment: @Ole V.V.: no it doesn’t. The possibility that the string is shorter than `15` can’t be handled by `StringUtils.truncate`, as that method doesn’t see that number and it will handle `-1` the same way, `String.substring` does (by thowing an exception).

Comment: You may use `str.lastIndexOf(' ', 15)` (with a char argument rather than a `String`).

Comment: Comment by @OleV.V. did the job. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Here a utility method which addresses your requirements and takes the comments of @David Wallace and @Ole V.V. into account as well:

```
public static String truncate(String str, int length, String delim) {
    int len = Math.max(0, length);
    if (str.length() <= len) return str;
    else {
        int idx = str.lastIndexOf(delim, len);
        return str.substring(0, idx != -1 ? idx : len);
    }
}
```

- it should be efficient because it performs the least expansive operations first.
- it addresses the case when `delim` is not found in the first `length` characters.
- it is flexible according the *length* and *delimiter*.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way is to use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.truncate() method.

It also gives you good performance.

Answer (score 0):

### Usage

```
truncate("SO is great website",15); //"SO is great"
truncate("SO is great website",11); //"SO is great"
truncate("SO is great website",1); //""
```

### Code

```
private String truncate(String s, int limit) {
    int n = s.length();
    int last = Math.min(n, limit);

    if (last < n) {
        //scroll to start index of the last word
        while (last > 0 && !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(last))) last--;
    }

    //strip last whitespaces
    while (last > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(--last))) ;

    return last == 0 ? "" : s.substring(0, last + 1);
}
```

### Test

```
public class StringTruncateTest {
    @Test
    void empty() throws Throwable {
        assertThat(truncate("", 0), equalTo(""));
    }

    @Test
    void limitGreaterThanLength() {
        assertThat(truncate("", 1), equalTo(""));
    }

    @Test
    void dropsLastWhitespaces() throws Throwable {
        assertThat(truncate("foo ", 4), equalTo("foo"));
    }

    @Test
    void donotLimitToWordLastPos() throws Throwable {
        assertThat(truncate("foo", 1), equalTo(""));
    }

    @Test
    void donotLimitToWordLastPosButHavingAnyWordsBefore() throws Throwable {
        assertThat(truncate("java website", "java web"), equalTo("java"));
    }

    @Test
    void limitToLastThatNotContainingAnyWhitespaces() throws Throwable {
        assertThat(truncate("foo", 3), equalTo("foo"));
    }

    @Test
    void limitToLastThatContainingAnyWhitespaces() {
        assertThat(truncate("java website tutorial", "java website"), equalTo("java website"));
    }

    @Test
    void limitToEnd() throws Throwable {
        assertThat(truncate("java website", "java website"), equalTo("java website"));
    }

    private String truncate(String input, String sub) {
        return truncate(input, sub.length());
    }

    private String truncate(String s, int limit) {
        int n = s.length();
        int last = Math.min(n, limit);

        //scroll to start index of the last word
        if (last < n) while (last > 0 && !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(last))) last--;

        //strip last whitespaces
        while (last > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(--last))) ;

        return last == 0 ? "" : s.substring(0, last + 1);
    }    

}
```

Comment: Not what I meant. I mean when you post code, you should explain exactly how your code achieves what the OP is looking for.

Comment: It’s more lines of code than in the question and in the other answer (not counting the test), and I don’t think it’s clearer. Are there any advantages?

Comment: @OleV.V. if I refactoring the code like this? and you see again is that clearly?

Comment: @OleV.V. OP who emphasize the performance,so I'm not doing refactoring steps.